# beatifullsoap4 diretiva wrap

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How to make wrap with inconplete html code?

```
content="<head></head><a href="http://example.com/">I linked to <i>example.com</i></a><p>#1</p><p>#2</p>"


soup = bs4.Beautifulsoup(content, 'html.parser')

tag = soup.new_tag('html')
tag.wrap(soup)
```

I tried loop, but tags mistakes.

```
tag = soup.new_tag('html')
for item in soup.find_all():
    tag.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


content="""<head></head><a href="http://example.com/">I linked to <i>example.com</i></a><p>#1</p><p>#2</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.new_tag('html')
for item in soup.find_all():
    tag.append(item)

print(tag)


<html><head></head><a href="http://example.com/">I linked to </a><i>example.com</i><p>#1</p><p>#2</p></html>
```

[I linked to](http://example.com/) *example.com*

#1

#2

Comment: what output you get ?

Comment: Like this:
<html><head></head><a href="http://example.com/">I linked to <i>example.com</i></a><p>#1</p><p>#2</p><html>

Comment: what exactly you cant to get ?

Comment: i want create a tag html and tag body mistake, around all html code.

Comment: the for apresented break html code: <body>
 <head>
 </head>
 <title>
  D76326impressao
 </title>
 <div>
 </div>
 <center>
 </center>
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 </table>
 <tr>
 </tr>
 <td>
 </td>
 <p>
 </p>